# ASP.Net Core web app POST method always receives NULL as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

1. In VS2017 I created new ASP.NET Core Web Application
2. I sample code Get methods works perfectly, but
3. POST method always receives null as parameter.

This method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("\n'" + value + "'\n");
}
```

I tried:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"msg": "hello"}' localhost:57084/api/values
```

In Post value is null.

Tried use POSTMAN: with all possible combinations of content type and message body. NULL as input.

Tried to pass value with '=' as someone suggested. Same, null.

Tried to use dynamics.

```
public void Post(dynamic value)...
```

, Value is null.

Tried to use

```
public void Post([FromBody] HttpRequestMessage request)...
```

-- same, null.

When I used

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(HttpRequestMessage request) // [FromBody]
{
    string body = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var headers = request.Headers;
}
```

Request had properties: Method: "GET", RequesrURL=null, Headers=null, Content=null

It might be something small and stupid, but I cannot seems to find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Create a model to hold the data sent to the controller action.

For example, given the following JSON

```
{"msg": "hello"}
```

A strongly typed model would look like

```
public class MyModel {
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

Then refactor the controller to expect that model

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]MyModel model){
    //...access the model

    return Ok(model); //echo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The request parameter passed through the request is different from the expected one. 
If you define your action expecting a string parameter called "value", the expected parameter when you call the request will be:

```
{ "value" : "something here" }
```